# MySQL Error 1030 When Importing Large Database

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1030

I have a database dump that is 22GB in size. I've been using an installation of MySQL 5.6.23 on MacOS on a daily basis for well over a year without a problem.

When I tried importing this large database via the command line, I immediately got an error:

> ERROR 1030 (HY000) at line 25: Got error 168 from storage engine

[Based on this page, I upped the open_files_limit = 20240000 in the /etc/my.cnf file.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/138505/receiving-general-error-1030-got-error-168-from-storage-engine)

Now when I try importing the file, it runs for an hour and a half before failing with the same error (just at line number 16815 in the error instead of 25).

My coworkers who have successfully imported the database have the same version of MySQL, the standard boilerplate my.cnf file, and the same version of MacOS.

I have since tried completely uninstalling MySQL and reinstalling it, only to have it fail with the same error after an hour and a half.

My system has no /etc/security/limits.conf file.

I am completely blocked by my inability to get my dev environment up to date, and everyone in my office is stumped. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Here is the head of the file I'm trying to import:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.5.54, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: our_host    Database: gms_dpe
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version       5.6.19

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
```

The database's engine is InnoDB.
If you need more information about the database, please let me know.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the data file from which you're importing? And the tool you're using to import?   Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Updated. I was not sure what to say about the datafile, please advise on what sort of information is useful.

Comment: Does this help? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/138505/receiving-general-error-1030-got-error-168-from-storage-engine

Comment: @cwallenpoole Thanks, but no. I already tried the Accepted Answer from that page of upping mysql open_file_limit by a factor of 10.

Comment: What happens if you split the file?

Comment: How are you trying to import this? Using the `mysql` command client?